# Make an Items attribute searchable (taxonomy using existing attribute)

Tags: database, taxonomy

Huge item database 40,000+ entries unfortunately one of the attributes is not searchable, the "address" field is not in a category or location taxonomy. I've created a custom taxonomy but it doesn't search from within the existing database. Is there anyway to make this part of the database searchable without re-uploading entire database?  These is an existing working taxonomy within the database structure named

taxonomy-ait-dir-item-category.php

could I not just duplicate and replace all code that says 'category' with address since the attribute already exists?